# Outlook VBA \ Macro conversion to Add-in

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, visual-studio-2015

I'm in the process of converting some Outlook VBA \ Macros into add-ins.
So far I'm not having a lot of luck piping this code over to VS2015 w\Office Dev Tools.

I've created a ribbon \ group \ buttons \ I can see it in Outlook and everything looks good but I'm receiving an error.

**--ORIGINAL MACRO--**

```
Sub Request()
  Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("Shared Documents")
  Set myItem = objFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Note.Request")
       myItem.Display
End Sub
```

I'm seeing that Set is no longer permitted so they've all been defined.

This particular line seems to be the problem.
Session and\or GetDefaultFolder are returning Null and causing a runtime exception.

**Error -- "System.NullReferenceException" --**

```
    objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("Shared Documents")
```

The suggestion from VS is to use the Sub "New" along with a few others that don't seem applicable.

A little help please. :-)
Seems that I'm getting a mix of programming types mixed up from the VS error resolution suggestions.

Thank you. -Chris

Comment: Can you check if it's Session or GetDefaultFolder? If it's Session, you can try to replace the Session reference above with myOlApp.Session.

Comment: Alright I gave that a try but I receive the same result. After swapping in the OlApp.Session I get an underlined "olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders" ---objFolder = myOlApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("Shared Documents") ----- Same Null Reference, I see why it would be Null because the value isn't obtained until the Outlook session feeds the path to the program.

Comment: To make clear what I'm doing: I'm trying to open a Custom Form which is stored in the All Public Folders \ Shared Documents \ FormName  --Macro does this perfectly fine but I'd like it to be an add-in so I can deploy it as a package along with the other functions that work.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, it's working meow.
Found this handy dandy webpage in case someone needs some pointers:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313800

When you create a project for Outlook Add-ins it's being coded in VB.Net

Thank you **DanL** for the input, it got me thinking and searching again.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook._Application
    objOutlook = New Outlook.Application()
    Dim objNS As Outlook._NameSpace = objOutlook.Session
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder =
         objNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("Shared Documents")

    Dim myItem = objFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Note.CustomFormName")
    myItem.Display()

End Sub
```